# Why is @? used when referring router.request_context?

Tags: 8, symfony-services

In `core.services.yml` we have:

```
calls:
  - [setContext, ['@?router.request_context']]
```

But `router.request_context` is also defined in `core.services.yml` (and it depends on `request_stack` alone which doesn't depend on anything) so I can't see how could this become an invalid reference.

So why is `@?` used here?

Comment: Seems to be because of Simpletest: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2223593

Comment: `git blame` points to https://www.drupal.org/node/2062745 where it was added originally with `@?` without any explanation so that doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry I’m not sure what you mean - why would the lack of an explanation in the original commit mean it’s not related to the discussion/comments in the other (more recent) issue surrounding simpletest?

Comment: Nothing in the issue you linked explains the necessity of `@?` for simpletest either. If you have an environment where you can use the definition of url_generator from core.services.yml then you can also use router.request_context from the same.